# put input with spaces as a single element in array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, unix

I have a file from which I extract the first three columns using the `cut` command and write them into an array.

When I check the length of the array , it is giving me four. I need the array to have only 3 elements.

I think it's taking space as the delimiter for array elements.

```
aaa|111|ADAM|1222|aauu

aaa|222|MIKE ALLEN|5678|gggg
aaa|333|JOE|1222|eeeee

target=($(cut -d '|' -f1-3 sample_file2.txt| sort -u ))
```

Comment: You need the first three fields of each line as single array elements? See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: yes, i need the first three fields as a single element in an array

Answer (score 2):

In `bash` 4 or later, use `readarray` with process substitution to populate the array. As is, your code cannot distinguish between the whitespace separating each line in the output from the whitespace occurring in "Mike Allen". The `readarray` command puts each line of the input into a separate array element.

```
readarray -t target < <(cut -d '|' -f1-3 sample_file2.txt| sort -u)
```

Prior to `bash` 4, you need a loop to read each line individually to assign to the array.

```
while IFS='' read -r line; do
    target+=("$line")
done < <(cut -d '|' -f1-3 sample_file2.txt | sort -u)
```

Comment: Hi, can we use readarray in bash? I have got the error when i tried the above command

Comment: You do need to be using `bash` 4 or later. Otherwise, you need to use something a little messier.

Comment: I had a typo in my description. The loop version should work for any thing in the 3.x series.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
IFS=$'\n' target=($(cut -d '|' -f1-3 sample_file2.txt| sort -u ))
```

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n' target=($(cut -d '|' -f1-3 sample_file2.txt| sort -u ))
echo ${#target[@]}
echo "${target[1]}"
```

Output:

```
3
aaa|222|MIKE ALLEN
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, using the infamous `eval`,

```
eval target=($(cut -sd '|' -f1-3 sample_file2.txt | sort -u | \
               xargs  -d\\n printf "'%s'\n"))
```